# CodeName one : theme.xml becom empty after shutting down my PC

Tags: java, windows, mobile, codenameone

I Have problem guys, I have edited my theme.res file and so on and everything went perfect but sometime the CodeName one Designer throws an "JAVA IO Exception" but whene I ran my application it work Fine every thing is saved!
But suddenly my PC shutDown due to electricity problem, and whene I open up my project theme.res was empty!
I looked up for theme.xml it was empty! but theme folder containes my Theme details!

Comment: See this: http://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-track-designer-guibuilder-issues.html I will need a stack trace of the error and way to reproduce it